# SwiftUI: Why doesn't picker display?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

I'm following this tutorial to implement a picker using SwiftUI.

The tutorial preview looks like this:

[image: picker screenshot]

Whereas I have no picker in my preview:

[image: no picker]

Why doesn't my code display a picker?

Here's my view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CheckoutView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
    @State private var paymentType = "Cash"

    let paymentTypes = ["Cash", "Credit Card", "iDine Points"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Section {
                Picker("How do you want to pay?", selection: $paymentType) {
                    ForEach(paymentTypes, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Payment")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct CheckoutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CheckoutView()
            .environmentObject(Order())
    }
}
```

(I'm using Xcode 13.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely an older video, if you set the `pickerStyle` to `.wheel`

```
Picker("How do you want to pay?", selection: $paymentType) {
    //Your code
}.pickerStyle(.wheel)
```

you will get that look. Right now it is likely a menu style. When you don't set the type Apple can pick which style to use.